# What concept in category theory can be used to represent a typeclass?

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, computer-science, category-theory, adhoc-polymorphism

In Haskell programming language,  according to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Translating_categorical_concepts_into_Haskell

> 59.2.2 Translating categorical concepts into Haskell
>
> 1. We work in the category `Hask` and its subcategories.
> 2. Objects are types.
> 3. Morphisms are functions.
> 4. Things that take a type and return another type are type
>      constructors.
> 5. Things that take a function and return another function are
>      higher-order functions.
> 6. **Typeclasses**, along with the polymorphism they provide, make a nice
>      way of capturing the fact that in category theory things are often
>      deﬁned over a number of objects at once.

What concept in category theory is a typeclass represented as? As a subcategory of `Hask`?

Comment: I don't think typeclasses per se correspond to anything important in category theory, it's more that many category-theory ideas can be expressed _as type classes_.

Comment: A typeclass is simply a collection of objects and morphisms, specific to some object. This doesn't correspond to anything in particular.

Answer (score 8):

[According to Dominic Orchard](https://dorchard.blog/2011/10/18/subcategories-in-haskell-exofunctors/), typeclasses correspond to subcategories of Hask:

> The instances of a single parameter type class can be interpreted as describing the members of a set of types (or a relation on types for multi-parameter type classes). In a type signature, a universally quantified type variable constrained by a type class constraint represents a collection of types that are members of the class. E.g. for the `Eq` class, the following type signature describes a collection of types for which there are instances of `Eq`:
>
> ```
>  Eq a => a
> ```
>
> The members of `Eq` are a subcollection of the objects of **Hask**. Similarly, the type:
>
> ```
>  (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b)
> ```
>
> represents a subcollection of the morphisms of **Hask** mapping between objects in the subcollection of objects which are members of `Eq`. Thus, the `Eq` class defines an `Eq`-subcategory of **Hask** with the above subcollections of objects and morphisms.